How to start a LightDM session in an already-running, remote X server?
I have Xephyr running in machine1, with this command line. It starts the X server in a window, no problem:
Xephyr -listen tcp -listen unix -listen local -br -ac -noreset -screen 1366x768 :1

I can log onto machine2 and do this:
export DISPLAY=machine1:1
xterm &

And it runs within Xephyr's window in machine1's screen, all ok. What I really want to do in machine2 is start a lightdm session and have the login appear in machine1's screen. I'm using Linux Mint 21 with Cinnamon. I searched and couldn't find a solution.

Please read this https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. Your question is better suited in Linux Mint forum.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
